# IOS/Objective-c: code reduction within animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have this simple animation that fades in several labels, one at a time. But I wonder if it is possible to reduce the code with this logic?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
    [_latLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
    [_firstLat setAlpha:0.9f];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
        [_lonLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
        [_firstLon setAlpha:0.9f];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
            [_speedLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
            [_firstSpeed setAlpha:0.9f];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
                [_realNorthLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
                [_firstReal setAlpha:0.9f];
            }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
                    [_magneticNorthLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
                    [_firstMagnetic setAlpha:0.9f];
                }];
            }];
        }];

    }];

}];
```

Comment: Use functions with delay start

Comment: well i'm trying your suggestion but i get plenty of errors...

Comment: So you built a function with a delay start parameter and you're getting an error well how you did it

Comment: you mean using this?  [UIView animateWithDuration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> delay:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> options:<#(UIViewAnimationOptions)#> animations:<#^(void)animations#> completion:<#^(BOOL finished)completion#>]

Comment: Im doing like this but the result is not the same:

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{[_latLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
        [_firstLon setAlpha:0.9f];
        [_speedLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
        [_firstSpeed setAlpha:0.9f];
        [_realNorthLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
        [_firstReal setAlpha:0.9f];
        [_magneticNorthLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
        [_firstMagnetic setAlpha:0.9f];
        
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        nil;
                     }];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the need to perform operation on 2 label objects while executing any single section of the animation block, create a `dictionary` structure wherein `section indexes` define the *chronological* order of the sections animations to be performed & each section index contains an `array` of label objects.
A simple iterating loop over this structure christened here as `dictionaryOfSectionedLabels` can help achieve the desired alternate animation implementation.

```
NSDictionary<NSNumber *, NSArray *> *dictionaryOfSectionedLabels = @{ @0: @[_latLabel, _firstLat],
                                                                      @1: @[_lonLabel, _firstLon],
                                                                      @2: @[_speedLabel, _firstSpeed],
                                                                      @3: @[_realNorthLabel, _firstReal],
                                                                      @4: @[_magneticNorthLabel, _firstMagnetic]
                                                                    };

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < dictionaryOfSectionedLabels.allKeys.count; i++) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.5*i options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{

        UILabel *firstLabel = [dictionaryOfSectionedLabels[@(i)] firstObject];
        UILabel *secondLabel = [dictionaryOfSectionedLabels[@(i)] lastObject];

        firstLabel.alpha = 0.9f;
        secondLabel.alpha = 0.9f;

    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: glad to help @FuManchu :)

Answer (score 1):

Creating an NSDictionary of your labels can be tedious and confusing code to read in the future. I'd recommend you just create a method.

```
-(void)customFadeForLabel:(UILabel *)theLabel withDelay:(float)delayAmount {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f 
                          delay:delayAmount 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:^{
                         [theLabel setAlpha:0.9f];
                     }completion:nil];

}
```

Then just call it as needed with delays

```
[self customFadeForLabel:_latLabel withDelay:0.00f];
[self customFadeForLabel:_firstLat withDelay:0.00f];

[self customFadeForLabel:_lonLabel withDelay:0.50f];
[self customFadeForLabel:_firstLon withDelay:0.50f];

[self customFadeForLabel:_speedLabel withDelay:1.00f];
[self customFadeForLabel:_firstSpeed withDelay:1.00f];

[self customFadeForLabel:_realNorthLabel withDelay:1.50f];
[self customFadeForLabel:_firstReal withDelay:1.50f];

[self customFadeForLabel:_magneticNorthLabel withDelay:2.00f];
[self customFadeForLabel:_firstMagnetic withDelay:2.00f];
```